# Hiding the Arguments from a Rehosted workflow designer

Tags: wpf, workflow-foundation-4

I have a rehosted workflow. I'm creating a custom way users can input arguments. I want to remove the Arguments section from the WorkflowDesigner.View.

is that possible?[image]

Cheers

theHaggis

Comment: Yes.  You can always plunge through the children of the design surface until you find the Arguments control and set its Visibility to Collapsed.  No code, so no answer.  [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) will tell you exactly how to find it.

Comment: In my case, the Arguments tab does not show. Did you do anything special for it to show?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After creating your [WorkflowDesigner](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.presentation.workflowdesigner.aspx):

```
var designer = new WorkflowDesigner();
```

You can access various options, including the one where you show/hide bar items, using [DesignerView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.presentation.view.designerview.aspx), like this:

```
var designerView = designer.Context.Services.GetService<DesignerView>();

designerView.WorkflowShellBarItemVisibility =
    ShellBarItemVisibility.Imports |
    ShellBarItemVisibility.MiniMap |
    ShellBarItemVisibility.Variables |
    // ShellBarItemVisibility.Arguments | <-- Uncomment to show again
    ShellBarItemVisibility.Zoom;
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't think it's possible. The WorkflowDesigner control and its view don't offer many properties or methods to manipulate their contents. You can use [WPF Inspector](http://wpfinspector.codeplex.com/) to see what the actual designer structure is like.

[image]

Comment: Hmmm, so WPF Inspector can locate the Arguments StatusBarItem (via the same API you can access given the root UIElement of the designer), and StatusBarItem has a [Visibility property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.visibility.aspx)... Hmmm....

Comment: There's a well-known way of doing it. Reverse-enginnering isn't a good option here, at all. Check my answer.